# What preposition should I use in this phrase?

Tags: prepositions

I wnat to say 'this ilness invoves women who are in their fertility age'. 
Which preposition is appropriate? 
Should I use related to or relating to
which is an inflammatory disease RELATING TO/ RELATED TO estrogen and it involves 2 to 10 percent of the women IN/AT/INSIDE their fertility age range. 
If none of them is good enough to be used in this sentence, please share your ideas. 
Thank you

Comment: Could you please proofread your question, and summarize your own research?

Comment: ' . . . women of reproductive age. . .' ?

Comment: "...an inflammatory disease that relates to oestrogen"

Comment: Well, this is completely different from what I asked! Does anyone edit questions here? This is my original question: Is it grammatically correct to use with at the beginning of a sentence? Did I use it correctly here in this passage? "With translation being used as the communication means between/among companies and advertisers, many people could express their opinions on advertisements and billboards in seminars, lectures, papers, and during conferences through the years."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

> This illness involves women who are of childbearing age.

-or-

> This illness involves women who are in their childbearing years.

The adjective "[childbearing](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/childbearing)" means capable of, suitable for, or relating to the bearing of a child or of children.  The first sentence above is probably more precise, but the second sentence above is probably how more people would say it.  The caveat with the second sentence, however, is that some might infer that it only effects women who have actually had children, which is why the first one is probably better.